# Browser forward button not active with React.js

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a react application using typescript that is set up like a wizard with different pages in each step. I have a 'Forward' and 'Back' button on the page that I created and they work just fine.
What the problem is the browser forward button, I got the back button working. Everytime i go back either using the browser button or my custom back button the forward button is always disabled.

on one page I have this code that fixes my back button

```
const [finishStatus, setFinishStatus] = useState(false)
const onBackButtonEvent = () => {
   if (!finishStatus) {
  setFinishStatus(true)
  history.push('previous page')
   }
  }


 useEffect(() => {
   window.history.pushState(null, 'null', window.location.pathname)
   window.addEventListener('popstate', onBackButtonEvent)
   return () => {
     window.removeEventListener('popstate', onBackButtonEvent)
   }
  }, [])
```

can i do something similar to this for the forward button?
I have tried several solutions I have found but nothing is working.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because the browser's forward button is only enabled when the user is navigated *back* in the browsing history.  Which isn't what's happening here:

```
history.push('previous page')
```

You're navigating the user *forward* to a page they were previously viewing, but it's still forward navigation.  The browser isn't going to intuitively look at the page and see if it's familiar based on the user's browser history.

To navigate the user backward in standard JavaScript, you might do something like:

```
history.go(-1)
```

or:

```
history.back()
```

Or, if your `history` object is imported from `react-router-dom` or something of that nature, it might be:

```
history.goBack()
```

You may need to check the vendor documentation depending on the nature of your `history` object.

Comment: actually removing all the useEffect code gave me the forward button . not I have to hit the button 2 times on each page . that may be something else that is happening in my code